# How to use linkbutton in repeater using C# with ASP.NET 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, asplinkbutton

In asp.net I have a table in database containing questions,date of submission and answers.On page load only questions appear.now i want to use any link which on clicking show answers and date specified in table data, either in textbox or label and clicking again on that link answer disappear again like expand and shrink on click.
So what coding should i use for this in C#?

Comment: Have you looked at `jQuery` and `jQuery-UI`?

Comment: i don't know about jquery

Comment: What have you been able to do?

Comment: sir, i'm learning asp.net so i just know about simple commands.in repeater i'm just able to show data on page load only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you could handle the [ItemCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand.aspx) event of the Repeater.

Place a LinkButton control for the link that you want the user to click in the Repeater's item template.  Set the CommandName property of this to something meaningful, like "ShowAnswers".  Also, add a Label or TextBox control into the Repeater's item template, but set their Visible property to false within the aspx markup.

In the code-behind, within the ItemCommand event handler check if the value of `e.CommandName` equals your command ("ShowAnswers").  If so, then find the Label or TextBox controls for the answers and date within that Repeater item (accessed via `e.Item`).  When you find them, set their Visible property to true.

Note: you could take a different approach using AJAX to provide a more seamless experience for the user, but this way is probably simpler to implement initially.

I think the implementation would look something like this.  Disclaimer: I haven't tested this code.

Code-Behind:

```
void Repeater_ItemCommand(Object Sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "ShowAnswers")
    {
        Control control;

        control = e.Item.FindControl("Answers");
        if (control != null)
            control.Visible = true;

        control = e.Item.FindControl("Date");
        if (control != null)
            control.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

ASPX Markup:

```
<asp:Repeater id="Repeater" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater_ItemCommand">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton id="ShowAnswers" runat="server" CommandName="ShowAnswers" />
    <asp:Label id="Answers" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Answers") %>' Visible="false" />
    <asp:Label id="Date" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Date") %>' Visible="false" />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: sir, i used this code but on clicking link button no event happens. I'm just unable to recognize the problem that how click event will happen..?