# Get asp:Hyperlink data-attribute through onclick event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp:Hyperlink with a data-attribute containing a value (a number in this case).

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hypTest" href="testwebsite.com" CssClass="button-close" data-test="1" runat="server" Text="Testlink" onclick="dosomething"></asp:HyperLink>
```

How can I access the data attribute from this HyperLink in the codebehind when a user clicks that exact link. (there will be multiple similar links)

Also note that the onclick shown above does not work for me.
It does not access the dosomething method.

```
protected void dosomething()
{
    //get the data-test value
}
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the server click event - use `LinkButton` instead of using `Hyperlink`.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="hypTest" CssClass="button-close" data-test="1" runat="server" Text="Testlink" onclick="dosomething"></asp:LinkButton>
```

For the dosomething event do it like this:

```
protected void dosomething(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

For the data attribute.  Take it from the `Attributes Collection`.

```
string testData = hypTest.Attributes["data-test"]
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the data attribute without knowing the ID?
In case of multiple generated links

Comment: @how you generate the multiple links ? In a repeater ?

Comment: @inside the repeater you no longer have the onclick event. You need to use item command - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861690/how-to-use-linkbutton-in-repeater-using-c-sharp-with-asp-net-4-5