# how to download a document from the database via a link button in a repeater control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to download a document from the database related to a specific employee by making use of a link button that is found inside a repeater control.The certificate is what I want to download as this is the name of the file inside the database.

This is my code for my repeater control:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterEmployee" runat="server" OnItemCommand="RepeaterEmployee_ItemCommand">            
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table runat="server" class="table table-default table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
            <tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;" ><asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageAlign="Middle"  ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Photo") %>' /></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align:middle;">
                    <%--<asp:Image ID="EmployeePhoto" runat="server" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle"  ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Photo") %>' />--%>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table runat="server" style="width:100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>First Name:</b></td>
                            <td><asp:Label ID="FirstName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Last Name:</b></td>
                            <td><asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("LastName") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Employee Code:</b></td>
                            <td><asp:Label ID="lblCode" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Code") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                        </tr>                                      
                            <td><b>Right Eye Corr Day/Night:</b></td>
                            <td><asp:Label ID="lblRightEyeCorrDayNight" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("RightEyeCorrDayNight") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Visual Field Left Day/Night:</b></td>
                            <td><asp:Label ID="lblVisualFieldLeftDayNight" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("VisualFieldLeftDayNight") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Visual Field Right Day/Night:</b></td>
                            <td><asp:Label ID="lblVisualFieldRightDayNight" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("VisualFieldRightDayNight") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Colour Vision Day/Night:</b></td>
                            <td><asp:Label ID="lblColourVisionDayNight" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ColourVisionDayNight") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Date Tested:</b></td>
                            <td><asp:Label ID="lblDateTested" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("DateTested") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Medical Report:</b></td>
                            <td>
                                 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnCommand="LinkButton1_Command" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Certificate") %>' CommandName="download">Download</asp:LinkButton>
                            </td>
                        </tr>         
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Improved formatting

Comment: Please look at Dr. Wily's Apprentice's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861690/how-to-use-linkbutton-in-repeater-using-c-sharp-with-asp-net-4-5

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the link button create simple anchor tag and bind the document name in the source of the tag while binding the repeater 
e.g.-
"
     <**a**>  href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg"  ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"   target="_blank" download>"

use can use the item data-bound event to bind the href(path of the document) of the button.

Please reply me if it is not working

Comment: Thanks @Shyam Sa, but what do you mean by an anchor tag ?

Comment: Html anchor tag which supports download attribute. Check the example above- Added an attribute "Download" in the end