# Error on button click: System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Byte[]'.'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am getting an error on this line within my code:

```
[bytes = DirectCast(sdr("MedicalCertificateID"), Byte())]
```

Do you know what is wrong?

```
  Protected Sub btnDownload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim MedicalCertificateID As Integer = Integer.Parse(TryCast(sender, LinkButton).CommandArgument)
        Dim bytes As Byte()
        Dim fileName As String, contentType As String

        Using conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("##").ConnectionString)

            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblMedicalResults WHERE MedicalCertificateID  = @MedicalCertificateID", conn)

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MedicalCertificateID", MedicalCertificateID)

                conn.Open()
                Using sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    sdr.Read()
                    bytes = DirectCast(sdr("MedicalCertificateID"), Byte())
```

Comment: Why are you trying to read a value that you already know? _MedicalCertificateID_ is used in the WHERE statement to find a record that matches that variable's value.

Comment: @Steve - Then what will be the best way to handle this ?

Comment: Please stop using `.AddWithValue` See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications

Comment: You say the "name of the file" is stored in the database. The name of a file would be a string. Is the file itself stored in the database? It would not be stored in an Integer datatype. You are changing an Integer to a Byte array. This would have nothing to do with a file or file name.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to convert an integer value to its byte representation you need only one line of code

```
 Dim bytes As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(MedicalCertificateID)
```

There is no need to run a query against the database because the variable *MedicalCertificateID* is used in the WHERE statement to find a record with the a field containing the value that you want to read back.
If you want to check the record existance then you should simply check the return value of sdr.Read with

```
Using sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    if sdr.Read() Then 
       ' record exists....
    End If 
End using
```

Comment: Could you possibly assist me in finding a solution to this question please. https://stackoverflow.com/q/56665839/11578396

Comment: Sorry, not an expert on ASP.NET